# Debug at design time

Tags: visual-studio, design-time

I have a bug at design time described [here](http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/vb-net-general-discussion/29451-events-cannot-set-object-passed-event-binding-service.html), but I don't get to make Visual Studio debug at design time.

> To debug at design time you need to go
>   to project properties on the debug tab
>   hit start external program and
>   navigate to where devenv.exe is.
>
> On the command line arguments place the path to your project
>   includning the project file name: 
>   SomeProject.vbproj

OK

> Set a break point in the main program
>   and then hit play to open a new VS
>   instance

Here "then hit play to open a new VS instance" is unclear. What kind of *play* should I hit (*Start Debugging*)?

> and it will load your project but you
>   will be debugging the project you
>   started it from so the code will break
>   even at design time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As best I can tell, the answer to this question is really simple: **The "Play" button that the instructions you found refers to is equivalent to the "Start Debugging" command.** I'm not sure who wrote those instructions, because calling it the "Play button" is a truly terrible choice.

There's a [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ytx0z24.aspx) available on MSDN that's probably clearer.

Comment: I make it as answer, because I made a sample that worked as the article describes. However this solution didn't work for my real project, don't know why... The breack point in the constructor was never reatched in design mode, only the error in the designer appeared.